# How to combine multiple rows into single row with different column per row's data when ID is the same

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this result from multiple inner joins. I would like to have this rows combine in 1 row with additional columns per data from the rows.

```
Select fp.idfp, fp.idperson, p.fname+' '+p.mname+' '+p.lname as Patient,
fp.date, m.idmed, n.medname+' '+n.meddosage+' '+n.medtype as MedicineName, m.quantity, m.date as [Date Dispense]
from FPTRANSAC fp
Inner Join PRECORD p
On fp.idperson = p.idperson

inner join MEDOUT m
ON fp.idfp = m.idtransac

inner join NEWMED n
on m.idmed = n.idmed

union all

Select i.idimmu, i.idperson, p.fname+' '+p.mname+' '+p.lname as Patient,
i.date, m.idmed, n.medname+' '+n.meddosage+' '+n.medtype as MedicineName, m.quantity, m.date as [Date Dispense]
from IMMUTRANSACTION i
Inner Join PRECORD p
On p.idperson = i.idperson

inner join MEDOUT m
ON i.idimmu = m.idtransac

inner join NEWMED n
on m.idmed = n.idmed
```

This is the result:

```
idfptran | idperson | Patient     | date     | idmed | MedicineName  | quantity | Date Dispense
F-1      | 00001    | Jenny Jones | datehere | 1     | Cetirizine    | 5        | datehere
F-1      | 00001    | Jenny Jones | datehere | 3     | Tylenol       | 8        | datehere
I-1      | 00015    | Mark Sawyer | datehere | 2     | Salbutamol    | 2        | datehere  
I-1      | 00015    | Mark Sawyer | datehere | 4     | Amoxicillin   | 3        | datehere
I-1      | 00015    | Mark Sawyer | datehere | 7     | Carbocisteine | 3        | datehere
```

I would want to have this table like this but I don't know if it is possible. Can you please help? I've been trying to solve this for days now :( Please help. I am using mssql. For the Date Dipense, it can get the last row's value of the same ID or the first.

```
idfptran | idperson | Patient     | date     | idmed | MedicineName  | quantity | idmed | MedicineName | quantity | idmed | MedicineName | quantity | Date Dispense
F-1      | 00001    | Jenny Jones | datehere | 1     | Cetirizine    | 5        | 3     | Tylenol      | 8        |       |              |          | datehere
I-1      | 00015    | Mark Sawyer | datehere | 2     | Salbutamol    | 2        | 4     | Amoxicillin  | 3        | 7     | Carbocisteine| 3        | datehere
```

Comment: The table you are trying to create would not be in first normal form.

Comment: This style of display sort of goes against everything you are trying to get away from with normalization. Is there some reason you want it displayed this way?

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft sql server

Comment: @haag1 Actually I have 2 transactions here.
1. The ImmuTransaction and FPTransac.
2. MEDOUT
So, in MEDOUT, I am just calling the id of the transaction(ImmuTransaction or FPTransac) to link all the medicine asked by the patient. The reason why I want the table to be like that so that every transaction, they can see what medicines were asked by the patient.

Comment: What you want is a pivot table Where you are grouping by a person.  I will work on code.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng . I tried to search from the internet but most of it just stuff rows in 1 column. If it is better in 1 column, it's okay as long as I can get the medicine name and quantity per row. like : Cetirizine (5), Tylenol (8)

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem, but from the looks of it you have to types of entities: one is the patient info, and the other is the meds info with a relationship of one to many. Why don't you do a query that returns two datasets: patient then meds.

Comment: @alans I'm sorry, I didn't get it :( I am actually a newbie and struggling to find out if this is even possible. If there are other ways, then I am open to it. I just don't know how and what to do.

Comment: @meandyou No worries boss. I'm just trying to get the idea of your model. Initially, I thought it would be a Patient associated with many meds because of your desired result. But when I look at it again, I see Transaction (one-to-one with meds) associated with a Patient with the perspective of the Patient. Correct?

Comment: @alans Yes. To make things clearer. I have a Patient table, then Transactions (ImmuTransaction and FPTransac which only gets the ID of the patients for transactions made). And I have Medicine (if Patients opt to have medicines, here I get the transaction ID since that transaction already has the patient's id stored).

Comment: @meandyou Ok. Got it. So what I was suggesting is to do two result sets. One the returns the Patient detail associated to the transactions and another that returns the Transactions detail. Doing the unions from different Transaction tables is fine because I'm assuming they'll have the same columns and their own unique Id. From there, the next question will be "How do I work that with C#" because you tagged it with C# but never mentioned anything about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a union I would propose first collecting all person related data into a table or query and then adding the other data like idmed, medicine name, ... from the other source tables in the next layer(s) using outer join(s) for each source.

Comment: Hi. I didn't get what your trying to tell me. I'm sorry. A newbie still learning and struggling and wondering if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("idfptran", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("idperson", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("idmed", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("MedicineName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("quantity", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date Dispense", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"F-1", "00001", "Jenny Jones", DateTime.Parse("4/8/19"), 1, "Cetirizine", 5, DateTime.Parse("4/8/19")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"F-1", "00001", "Jenny Jones", DateTime.Parse("4/8/19"), 3, "Tylenol", 8, DateTime.Parse("4/8/19")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"I-1", "00015", " Mark Sawyer", DateTime.Parse("4/8/19"), 2, "Salbutamol", 2, DateTime.Parse("4/8/19")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"I-1", "00015", " Mark Sawyer", DateTime.Parse("4/8/19"), 4, "Amoxicillin", 3, DateTime.Parse("4/8/19")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"I-1", "00015", " Mark Sawyer", DateTime.Parse("4/8/19"), 7, "Carbocisteine", 3, DateTime.Parse("4/8/19")});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { idperson = x.Field<string>("idperson"), dispense = x.Field<DateTime>("Date Dispense") }).ToList();

            int maxMedicenes = groups.Select(x => x.Count()).Max(x => x);

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("idfptran", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("idperson", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

            for (int i = 1; i <= maxMedicenes; i++)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add("idmed_" + i.ToString(), typeof(int));
                pivot.Columns.Add("MedicineName_" + i.ToString(), typeof(string));
                pivot.Columns.Add("quantity_" + i.ToString(), typeof(int));
            }
            pivot.Columns.Add("Date Dispense", typeof(DateTime));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["idfptran"] = group.First().Field<string>("idfptran");
                newRow["idperson"] = group.Key.idperson;
                newRow["Patient"] = group.First().Field<string>("Patient");
                newRow["date"] = group.First().Field<DateTime>("date");

                int i = 1;
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    newRow["idmed_" + i.ToString()] = row.Field<int>("idmed");
                    newRow["MedicineName_" + i.ToString()] = row.Field<string>("MedicineName");
                    newRow["quantity_" + i.ToString()] = row.Field<int>("quantity");
                    i++;
                }
                newRow["Date Dispense"] = group.Key.dispense;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. I forgot to tell you that the datas are not just that, every now and then, more transactions are being added. I still have 3 more tables to join also, I just used 2 transaction table this time.